# Timezone reset for both values, only need one

Tags: perl, datetime

The set_time_zone() is cause problems

```
$messagedate = \Datetime variable\
$messagedate_tz = $messagedate;

$messagedate_tz->set_time_zone('UTC');
$messagedate_tz->set_time_zone('America/Goose_Bay');
```

when i execute this . The time for messagedate is also reset to America/Goose_Bay.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that, by `\Datetime variable\` you mean an object of the DateTime class (or any other class, for that matter), your issue is that `$messagedate_tz = $messagedate;` creates a second reference to the same object, it does not create a new object.

You should instead use `$messagedate_tz = $messagedate->clone;` (again, assuming it's a DateTime object; other classes may have a different method name for creating a copy) to create a new object which is identical to the original one and can then be modified without affecting the original.